# Android SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null on decoding an image

Tags: java, android

This is a method to decode an image. When called, it throws SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null.

```
private static Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BufferedInputStream buffer=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer, null, o);
            try {
                buffer.reset();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while(o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && 
                  o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            // o2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            //buffer.close();

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer, null, o2);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
      return null;
    }
}
```

Kindly assist!

Comment: did you try to copy that file on tour pc and see it?

Comment: I cannot copy the file because it is saved to a temporary folder. After snapping, I crop then on decoding it throws the error on the logcat

Comment: If you want I can post you the code for my snap method.

Comment: so i'm 99% sure the file is corrupted, just use **adb pull** command

Comment: please how can I perform adb pull command on eclipse

Comment: you have problem with `decodeStream`, right? so `Log.d`  the `f.getAbsolutePath()` and use it for **adb pull**

Comment: But if I check if the file path exists it return true

Comment: ok do what you want...

Comment: What am supposed to get if I do adb pull on command prompt

Comment: the path: f.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: When I do that I >>>>>> remote object 'f.getAbsolutePath()' does not exist

Comment: what ??? what do you mean?

Comment: just `Log.d()`  f.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: Please hold on, my emulator is launching

Comment: This is the output>>>>>> /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.scan.demo/files/.temp_image239014980.jpg

Comment: so use it in **adb pull**

Comment: When I do it under my c drive root path. I get remote object does not exist

Comment: and what about **adb shell ls -l /the/path** ?

Comment: I get no such file or directory.

Comment: So what is happening, getAbsolutePath(), returns a path with image in it and adb says no image

Comment: so if it says: `no such file or directory`, then it means  there is no such file. period.

Comment: So what do I at this stage

Comment: who creates that file? where do you get that path from?

Comment: I got the path using an intent

Answer (score 1):

After hours of nightmare I was able to conquer using the below code:

```
if(file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!>>>>>>>>>>>>> About entering the decode file"); 
            Options var7 = new Options();
            var7.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
            this.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.file.getAbsolutePath(), var7);
            System.out.println(this.file.getAbsolutePath()+" <<<<<<<<<I AM HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" +
                    "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + this.file.toString());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Capture please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!>>>> FILE1 FAILED");
            }
```

It might help someone.